# Modularize header with sidemenu option into a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-foundation

I'm trying to modularize a header bar with an optional sliding sidebar menu. I'm currently using [angular-foundation](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/) and it's off-canvas component for the sidebar. The idea is that you can have a header bar that could trigger a sidebar menu to open (in pages where you need the menu) or just as a simple header without a menu (eg: when the user isn't logged in)

The issue is that the off-canvas sidebar requires two wrapping layers, that would wrap around the whole content of the page to facilitate the sliding of the menu, the pushing the content to the side.

My idea was to create a `<my-header>` directive, with a scope attribute called sidebar, that when set to true, would include an off-canvas sidebar menu on the page. Additionally I created another 'helper' directive called `<my-off-canvas>` which has a template with the required wrapping divs that use some class directives for their magic.

Here's the plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5f6gUh0AixRNibs1rZTa?p=preview

**Issues:** 
the `<my-off-canvas>` wrapper, won't get compiled to the template, it will remain as a `<my-off-canvas>` directive.
When I manually added the proper wrappers and class directives to make it work, there were some dependency issues, as some class directives `offCanvasList` and `leftOffCanvasToggle` require directives and controllers that are part of the 2 wrapping layers for the off-canvas functionality.

Currently looking for ideas on how I should implement this, maybe this approach isn't viable after all and I should opt for a different implementation? I'm open to suggestions and ideas as I'm not very experienced when it comes to directives.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bMtJmiVFnsTmYEhDscoj?p=preview)

You can include your myHeader directive in the myOffCanvas directive.  Adding ng-transclude will allow you to add the rest of your content in the markup. *Note that if you are using AngularJS 1.2.x, you have to use ng-transclude as an attribute (vs. as an element as I have in the demo)*

```
var app = angular.module('foundationDemoApp', ['mm.foundation']);
app.directive('myOffCanvas', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            sidebar : '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: 
            '<div class="off-canvas-wrap">' +
                '<div class = "inner-wrap">' +
                  '<my-header></my-header>' +
                  '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>'
    };
})
app.directive('myHeader', function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: [
            '<nav class="tab-bar">',
                '<section ng-if = "sidebar === true" class = "left-small">',
                    '<a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon"><span></span></a>',
                '</section>',
                '<section class="middle tab-bar-section">',
                    '<h1 class="title">Header Title</h1>',
                '</section>',
            '</nav>',
            '<aside ng-if= "sidebar === true" class="left-off-canvas-menu">',
                '<ul class="off-canvas-list">',
                    '<li><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>',
                    '<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>',
                    '<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>',
                    '<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>',
                '</ul>',
            '</aside>'
        ].join(''),

    };
})
```

Then in your markup you can use:

```
<my-off-canvas sidebar="true">
      <h3>All of your other content here...</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</p>
</my-off-canvas>
```

Comment: Nice approach, but I would like to hide the off-canvas implementational details, so that we shouldn't worry about wrapping the whole content with a <my-off-canvas>. Ideally it's gonna be up to the sidebar scope attribute of the header to wrap everything with <my-off-canvas> or not.
Moreover, I will need control over the <my-header> directive because in the cases there's not a sidebar menu, there might be a back button etc.

Comment: I suppose the easiest way then would be to use an attribute on the body.  It's the basically same concept, but uses a function to return the proper template (with or without the wrapper).  I wasn't exactly sure what you meant by needing control over the myHeader directive.  You'd have the same control over it, you'd just be placing it inside another template instead of your markup.  http://plnkr.co/edit/hunbl1dUslau6SitzJaf?p=preview

Comment: When I said I need control over  <my-header> I meant that instead of the hamburger icon that triggers the sidebar, there could be nothing (user is not logged-in) or there could be a back button. That's why I don't want <my-header>  to be hardcoded within the template of <my-offcanvas> I hope it makes sense now? Also using ui-router so it's a ui-view that contains everything, not the body itself